# Access GCP Debian VM in GUI mode

Tags: google-cloud-platform, debian-buster

** I am not a Linux expert.

I have spun a Debian 10 VM in GCP which i need to access like in a GUI mode and be able to download and install some required applications for development and experiment purposes.
I think i have installed xrdp, display GUI packages, firefox, apache2 etc, but not able to land into GUI mode or browser mode.

1- I can't invoke/run firefox with "Display" error - Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified
2- RDP from my local laptop also being refused with "connection refused" error.

Need some help.

Comment: check this https://cloud.google.com/architecture/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine

Comment: Thanks Dany (and Google),  It worked pretty well.